# How to play 32-bit Steam games on macOS 12.6 (Monterey)?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, 32-bit, steam

Apparently since macOS Catalina 10.15 Mac disabled support for 32-bit apps?

How can Steam games like Portal 2 be played on MacBooks that have been keeping up with macOS updates?

In my case I'd like to do this on Intel MacBooks from 2015.

Comment: If an Intel mac then you can run Mojave in a virtual machine.

Comment: Have two bootable systems and choose.

Comment: dual boot with a work partition running latest macOS and a game partition (or external disk) running Mojave. been doing this ever since Catalina -- the only annoyance is having to reset my workspace after all the reboots.

Answer (score 1):

I rolled my 2018 Mac Mini back to Mojave.

In hindsight, I wouldn't have done that (I lost a few factory-loaded apps).  I would have gotten a [very fast USB](https://amzn.to/3Z4w5cB) thumb drive and put a Mojave OS (and the games) on that.  That particular drive is what I used for my gaming until I got a slightly faster USB-C drive.  Apple [explains how to get previous versions of macOS, here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683).

MacWorld [has a procedure on that](https://www.macworld.com/article/673171/how-to-install-older-versions-of-macos-or-os-x.html).  You might need to use a partition on a second thumb drive to install the previous version OS X installer and then reboot to that thumb drive for the installation proper in case the 10.14 installer doesn't want to run under Monterey.